# How to insert data with this SQL relationship?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get all records from teacher tables row teacher_id, into timetables table row teachers_id, by using right join, i tried this code but data was not inserted in timetables coloumn teacher's id.

TimeTable looks like this:

```
teacher_id,student_id,class_id;
```

Here is my query:

```
select timetable.* from timetable right join teachers  on 
timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
```

Sample data:

```
    Teachers table:
    **teacher_id | teacher_name**
      1 | asa
      2 | saa
      3 | ddd
      4 | eee
```

Timetable table:

```
    **teacher_id | class_id | student_id**
```

Comment: You are doing selfjoin on `teachers` tables. If thats what you want then use `alias` for the tables. If you want to join two different table then thats not what you are doing currently in your query.

Comment: What is the timetable here???

Comment: @CoderofCode i tried this query; 
          select timetable.* from timetable right join teachers  on 
          timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
but data is not inserted in timetable.

Comment: @vinaychhabra time table is empty table which has 3 column, teacher_id, student_id and class_id, right now i am trying to get all teacher_id from teacher table into timetable column teacher_id.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find LEFT JOIN hard enough to understand... It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: @jarlh can you please modify my query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh i have added some data. please check question.

Comment: For both tables, please. And the expected result as well.

Comment: @jarlh timetable is empty, and expected result is 1,2,3,4 in timetable column teacher_id.

Answer (score 0):

try below : you write same table twice that's why error occured:

```
select teachers.teacher_id from teachers left join timetable on 
timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
```

Comment: thankyou, this command executed but i can't see any data inserted in timetable table?

Comment: do you have any data in timetable ? and also it's better if you give your table structure in question

Comment: modified by query a bit - check  now

Comment: timetable table has three row teachers_id,student_id,class_id, i want to get data in teachers_id from teacher table.

Comment: use left join then it'll give you all ids from teachers table - modified my answer - check now

Comment: when i executed your command, still no data is inserted in timetable column, teachers_id, i got this message;
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Answer (score 0):

As you said in question, you like to get all records data from teacher tables row. 
So if you like to see all data in teachers table use this:

```
select teachers.* from timetable right join teachers on 
timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
```

In another part you said,  you can't see any data inserted in timetable, if you like to see the rows in timetable, use it :

```
select timetable.* from timetable right join teachers  on 
    timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
```

and if you like to see both use it:

```
select timetable.*,teachers.* from timetable right join teachers  on 
    timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried your first code:
select timetable.* from timetable right join on teachers 
    timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id;
and got this error,
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on teachers 
    timetable.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"

Comment: Thankyou man, it worked, but i have three columns in timetable table, teacher_id,class_id and subjects_id, i have dummy data in all other tables, but when i tried to run your command for teachers_id, it executed successfully but all values were null, no data is inserted in timetable.